# Turning txt files into rows on a CSV using python

Tags: python, regex, csv, text-files

I have a folder filled with text files that all have names similar to these:

```
2014521RNC Reax to Obama on VA.txt
2014520W.H. Evades Questions On When Obama.txt
2012517Updated Research/  Obama Vets Roll Out.txt
```

So digits and then letters and/or characters. In each text file, there are words. I'm trying to write a script that will take the first string of digits and add that to a csv in a column titled "date." Then it should take the letters and/or characters after the digits and put those in a column titled "title." And then it should take the text inside the file and add that to a column titled "content." I got kind of far but not the whole cigar. When I run the script below, date = -1 and title = -1 for all of them. What have I don't wrong?

```
f = open('RNC.csv','w')
names = ['date', 'title', 'content']
dw = csv.DictWriter(f, names)
dw.writerow({k:k for k in names})
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in filenames:
        if not filename.endswith('.txt'):
            continue
        title = filename.find(r'\D*')
        date = filename.find(r'^\d*')
        open_doc = open(root + '/' + filename, 'r')
        content = open_doc.read().rstrip()
        open_doc.close()        
        dw.writerow({'date':date, 'title':title, 'content':content})
f.close()
```

Comment: I see that the dates are in `yyyy-m-d` format. How would it show December 5, 2014 for example? `2014125` or `20141205`?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pass the string object's `.find()` method a regular expression, and it doesn't recognize them and is returning `-1`. Try using the `re` module instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `filename.find(s)` returns the position of the substring `s` in `filename`. It returns `-1` when the substring isn't found.

You can use a regex to perform the matching instead:

```
import re

for filename in filenames:
  m = re.match("\A(\d+)(.*)\.txt\Z", filename)
  if m:
    date = m.group(1)
    title = m.group(2)
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't supply regular expressions as parameters to the `str.find` method, which would interpret them as literal substrings to try to find in the filename.  Probably what you need to do is something like this (after adding `import re` to the top of your script):

```
match = re.search(r'^(\d+)', filename)
date = match.group(1) if match else 'None'
match = re.search(r'(\D+)', filename)
title = match.group(1) if match else 'None'
```